# Multiple independent random number streams

Tags: probability-distributions

This question is somehow related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112183/multiple-instances-of-random-generator/112207#112207) one.

Having multiple streams of pseudo-random numbers known to be independent and with a uniform distribution (U1, U2,...,Un) I want to do Monte Carlo simulations in parallel.

In other words, one thread will have a full-period independent and uniformly distributed stream of pseudo-random numbers. Each thread will consume these numbers in four different functions (a,b,c,d).

My concern is about the distribution for each function: a(U1), b(U2 or U3 (depending on results from a)), c(U2 or U3)... and so on. Do I still need to make sure this distribution is indeed uniform across a, b, c, d? Failing to do so can make my simulation have flaws?

In summary,if I start using the pseudo-random numbers in a "random" fashion. Can I still be sure of the uniform distribution among the different parts?